# Resize picture depending on screen PPI and known object size

Tags: image-processing

This software should be able to detect the PPI of the screen on which it is used and be able to detect an element in the picture of which it knows the size.

From that it will up/down scale the picture to make it represent the real size of contents of the picture, when it is displayed on the screen as one pixel for one pixel size (original size or something)

With that, for example, I can be able to use a ruler in a picture from the screen, it will be at real size.

For example, screen is 100 pixel per inches, picture is 100x100 pixels, ruler on it represent an inch as 15 pixels: 100/15*100. Now the picture is 667x667 pixels and the ruler holds 100 pixels per inches on the screen. When the picture is zoomed as original on the screen, sizes are correct.